# ATTINY 85 - sleep watchdog time changes after first reset

Tags: arduino, sleep, watchdog, attiny

I'm writing a simple program on my ATTINY 85. The program is supposed to light the LED pin when chip is awake, and turn it off when it is asleep. 
However, when I set watchdog timer to reset after 0.5 s, it does so on first reset, and then resets after only ~100ms. 
I checked it using an oscilloscope, prinstcreen is under this link:
https://i.snag.gy/WovBsf.jpg

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * Sketch for testing sleep mode with wake up on WDT.
 * Donal Morrissey - 2011.
 * ATTINY85
 */

#include <TinyWireM.h>                  // I2C Master lib for ATTinys which use USI - comment this out to use with standard arduinos
#include <LiquidCrystal_attiny.h>          // for LCD w/ GPIO MODIFIED for the ATtiny85


#include <avr/sleep.h> 
#include <avr/power.h>
#include <avr/wdt.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

//uwaga na numer pinu! nie używać tego z resetem
#define OUT_PIN 3

#define GPIO_ADDR     0x27
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(GPIO_ADDR, 16, 2); // set address & 16 chars / 2 lines

volatile int f_wdt=1;


/***************************************************
 *  Name:        ISR(WDT_vect)
 *
 *  Returns:     Nothing.
 *
 *  Parameters:  None.
 *
 *  Description: Watchdog Interrupt Service. This
 *               is executed when watchdog timed out.
 *
 ***************************************************/
ISR(WDT_vect){
  if(f_wdt == 0){
    f_wdt=1;

  }
  else{
//      lcd.clear();
//      lcd.print("WDT overrun");
//      delay(500);
  }
}


/***************************************************
 *  Name:        enterSleep
 *
 *  Returns:     Nothing.
 *
 *  Parameters:  None.
 *
 *  Description: Enters the arduino into sleep mode.
 *
 ***************************************************/
void enterSleep(void)
{
//  lcd.clear();
//  lcd.print("Asleep...");

  set_sleep_mode( SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN );   /* EDIT: could also use SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN for lowest power consumption. */
  sleep_enable();

  /* Now enter sleep mode. */
  sleep_mode();

  /* The program will continue from here after the WDT timeout*/
  sleep_disable(); /* First thing to do is disable sleep. */

  /* Re-enable the peripherals. */
  power_all_enable();

}



/***************************************************
 *  Name:        setup
 *
 *  Returns:     Nothing.
 *
 *  Parameters:  None.
 *
 *  Description: Setup for the serial comms and the
 *                Watch dog timeout. 
 *
 ***************************************************/
void setup()
{
  /*  Setup the LCD */
  lcd.init();                           // initialize the lcd
  lcd.backlight();                      // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0,0);
  lcd.print("Initializing...");
  delay(500);

  /*** Setup the WDT ***/

  /* Clear the reset flag of watchdog interrupts, so that they are available again. */
  MCUSR &= ~(1<<WDRF);

  /* Enable configuration changes
   */
  WDTCR |= (1<<WDCE) | (1<<WDE);

/*
WDP3 WDP2 WDP1 WDP0         Number of WDT     Typical Time-out at
                                             Oscillator Cycles     VCC = 5.0V

  0         0      0        0             2K (2048) cycles       16 ms
  0         0      0        1             4K (4096) cycles       32 ms
  0         0      1        0             8K (8192) cycles       64 ms
  0         0      1        1            16K (16384) cycles    0.125 s
  0         1      0        0            32K (32768) cycles    0.25 s
  0         1      0        1            64K (65536) cycles    0.5 s
  0         1      1        0            128K (131072) cycles 1.0 s
  0         1      1        1            256K (262144) cycles 2.0 s
  1         0      0        0            512K (524288) cycles 4.0 s
  1         0      0        1            1024K (1048576) cycles 8.0 s
*/
  /* set new watchdog timeout prescaler value */
  WDTCR =  0<<WDP3 | 1<<WDP2 | 0<<WDP1 |  1<<WDP0 ;

  /* Enable the WD interrupt (note no reset). */
  WDTCR |= (1<<WDIE); 

  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Initialisation complete.");
  delay(100); 
}



/***************************************************
 *  Name:        enterSleep
 *
 *  Returns:     Nothing.
 *
 *  Parameters:  None.
 *
 *  Description: Main application loop.
 *
 ***************************************************/
void loop()
{
  if(f_wdt == 1)
  {
//    lcd.clear();
//    lcd.print("Awake!");
    digitalWrite( OUT_PIN, HIGH );
    delay(1000);
    /* Don't forget to clear the flag. */
    f_wdt = 0;
    digitalWrite( OUT_PIN, LOW );
    /* Re-enter sleep mode. */
    enterSleep();
  }
  else
  {
    /* Do nothing. */
  }
}
```

Anyone got idea on how to fix this issue?

EDIT:
Alright, I managed to fix it. The only thing that I had to change is to enable WDT interrupt right before going to sleep, and then disable it after sleep. So the enetSleep function looks like this:

```
void enterSleep(void)
{
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Asleep...");

  /* Enable the WD interrupt (note no reset). */
  WDTCR |= (1<<WDIE); 

  set_sleep_mode( SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN );   /* EDIT: could also use SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN for lowest power consumption. */
  sleep_enable();

  /* Now enter sleep mode. */
  sleep_mode();

  /* The program will continue from here after the WDT timeout*/
  sleep_disable(); /* First thing to do is disable sleep. */

  /* Re-enable the peripherals. */
  power_all_enable();

  /* Disable the WD interrupt */
  WDTCR &= ~_BV(WDIE);
}
```

And, of course, I deleted

```
WDTCR |= (1<<WDIE);
```

line from setup.

Comment: If you found an answer yourself, post is as an answer. Don't put it into the question.

Comment: Why not simply being grateful that someone has posted the solution instead of just going away? Do you want him to mark his question as answer as well (doubt that it works).... Some people... tsssss